# List comprehensions with circular dependencies

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why is it possible to have a list comprehension that seemingly has a circular dependency?

For example, the following:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
nums = [num*num for num in nums]
```

where the list comprehension uses `nums` and the result of the list comprehension is put back in `nums`.

Or this more complicated example:

```
nodes0 = [node1 for node0 in nodes0 for node1 in (node0.left, node0.right) if node1]
```

where we use `nodes0` inside the list comprehension and then set the result of the list comprehension back to `nodes0`.

---

The above list comprehension snippet comes from the following code that returns the level-order traversal of a binary tree:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

    def levelOrder(root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not root:
            return
        nodes0 = [root]
        while nodes0:
            yield map(attrgetter('val'), nodes0)
            nodes0 = [node1 for node0 in nodes0 for node1 in (node0.left, node0.right) if node1]
```

For example, for the following tree:

[image: binary tree]

the code would return `[[3], [9, 20], [15, 7]]`

Comment: Because you are 1) first creating a new value using a comprehension expression and 2) having computed and expression, re-assigning it to a previous namespace. From the point of view of Python, there is no correlation between `[1, 2, 3]` and `[num*num for num in nums]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list created by the list comprehension has no "memory" that it was created using values from a list bound to the name `nums`. As a result, there is no dependency on the name `nums` nor on the previous value of that name to conflict with the new value of the name `nums`.

Put another way, list comprehensions are just *syntax*; they are not a separate type. The new value of `nums` is the list `[1,4,9]`; there is no way to tell from that *list*  whether it was created with `[num*num for num in nums]` or hard-coded as `[1,4,9]`.